# How to get date time from DB date in Ruby

Tags: ruby, date

I need to `get time and date` from database date like `"2015-08-27T12:09:36Z"`. I tried but not get any solutions where I get `date and time in different variable.`

I need to get it in `Ruby`. `No rails` in my application.

I used below code but not getting.

```
Time.strptime("2015-08-27T12:09:36Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z").in_time_zone
```

Any one have a experience in  it?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at [`Date.parse()`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) and its friend `Time.parse()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputations to comment so am posting comment as answer, are you looking for this

```
Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

Which will give the pattern you asked for. Z represent the time zone if you use

```
%z - Time zone as hour and minute offset from UTC (e.g. +0900)
          %:z - hour and minute offset from UTC with a colon (e.g. +09:00)
          %::z - hour, minute and second offset from UTC (e.g. +09:00:00)
  %Z - Time zone abbreviation name
```

Check for more

http://apidock.com/ruby/Time/strftime

My Updated answer after your comment

```
require 'date'

DateTime.parse("2015-08-27T12:09:36Z").strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')
```

In your code change **`Time.strptime('')`** to **`DateTime.strptime('')`**

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to `require 'date'`.  Ruby has built-in `Date` and `Time` classes without that `require`, but the library provides more functionality.

If you have a string retrieved from the database in ISO-8601 format, and you want to turn it into a date and time, just use `DateTime.iso8601(string)` to get a `DateTime` object.  You can extract the date and time components however you like after that.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'date' #=> true
irb(main):002:0> dt = DateTime.iso8601("2015-08-27T12:09:36Z") # DateTime object
irb(main):003:0> d = dt.to_date  # Date object
irb(main):004:0> t = dt.to_time  # Time object
```